# Turning off specgram auto-plotting in Jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, julia, spectrogram

I'm using Matplotlib's [specgram](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.html?highlight=specgram#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram) function, which has a form like:

```
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = specgram(x, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900)
```

where `Pxx`, `freqs`, `bins`, and `im` represent the periodogram, frequency vector, center of time bins, and the image.AxesImage instance. Additionally, you can feed in arguments (`**kwargs`) that get passed onto `imshow`.

I cannot seem to use `specgram` in a Jupyter Notebook, without producing a plot automatically. What argument can I pass into `specgram` that will stop it from plotting automatically?

I am not calling any `plt.show()` command. I've tried adding a semi-colon at the end of the line, and I've tried setting the final argument (`im`) as nothing, like this:

```
Pxx, freqs, bins, _ = specgram(x, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900);
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How is it related to Julia?

Comment: I'm using Pyplot in Julia, via a Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

From the PyPlot.jl docs: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl#non-interactive-plotting

> If you use PyPlot from an interactive Julia prompt, such as the Julia command-line prompt or an IJulia notebook, then plots appear immediately after a plotting function (plot etc.) is evaluated.
>
> However, if you use PyPlot from a Julia script that is run
> non-interactively (e.g. julia myscript.jl), then Matplotlib is
> executed in non-interactive mode: a plot window is not opened until
> you run show() (equivalent to plt.show() in the Python examples).

See the docs linked above for further reference.